# Sending email without smtp details from asp website?

Tags: php, asp.net, email, vs-web-site-project

I was using this PHP code with an HTML static website and it worked flawlessly! I am able to collect the senders email and us it as the actual sender! However i am trying to find something similar for implementing this in an asp website, any ideas?

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {

    $recipient="example@gmail.com,example@hotmail.com";
        $subject="Form to email message";
        $sender=$_POST["firstname"];
    $senderlast=$_POST["lastname"];
        $senderemail=$_POST["senderemail"];
        $message=$_POST["message"];
        $mailBody="First Name: $sender\nLast Name: $senderlast\nEmail: $senderemail\n\nMessage: $message";

        mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderemail>");

    header('Location: contact-us.html');
}
```

Note that i am not an expert neither in PHP or ASP and i might said something that doesn't make sense...

Comment: this just relies on the underlying mail subsystem in Unix/Linux, which is why it appears to work without SMTP details. Somewhere on the server there are still some mail settings which know how to reach the outside world. Windows does not have a direct equivalent AFAIK.

Comment: From memory you can perhaps use `CDOSYS` on a Windows machine - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mist/2015/10/12/things-to-check-when-a-cdo-mail-enabled-classic-asp-site-is-not-sending-mail-after-a-migration-to-iis7/ might be of use